# Loopback Cloudant adapter creates index on all_fields by default

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, cloudant, loopback, apiconnect

#### Description of issue

Sometime back it was noticed that loopback by default created indexes on all_feilds(on any db in cloudant) if you use loopback-cloudant-adapter. However Cloudant support strongly discourages that practice. We are in fact having a lot of performance issues with Cloudant lately and this was one of the recommendation by Cloudant support. So we were trying to figure out a way to make loopback-cloudant-connector not create index on all_feilds and only create it on the ones that we actually need. In words of one of our developers :

*We are trying to modify the existing all-field index to specific properties in cloudant models
To accomplish this we tried  modifying the existing design documents in cloudant and added specific index fields  and tried to invoke the  loopback services. The basic crud opertions failed with error Error: mango_idx :: {no_usable_index,missing_sort_index} and also upon app restart the cloudant design document was overwritten to  index on all fields.
We want support on modifying existing design documents to index on specific properties and also disable the default loopback functionality to create cloudant indexes on all_feilds_*

#### Additional information (Node.js version, LoopBack version, etc)

```
Loopback version : 3.6.0
Node js Version : 6.10
```

I have also opened a issue with loopback on their public github but wanted to check on stackoverflow too to see if someone has already encountered a similar issue. Given below is a link of the gitbub issue that was opened for this :

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-cloudant/issues/162